# Checking To Make Sure My Object isn't Partially Initialized

Tags: c#

I'm creating a simple application that takes a URL and a String and create the code for a hyperlink.

Here is my HyperLink Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

 namespace LinkIt_
{
class HyperLink
{
    private string url;
    private string text;

    public HyperLink()
    {

    }

    public HyperLink(string url,string text)
    {
        this.Website = url;
        this.Text = text;
    }


    public String Website
    {
        get
        {
            return url;
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Must have URL!");
            }

            this.url = value;
        }


    }

    public String Text
    {

        get
        {
            return text;
        }

        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Must have Text!");
            }
            this.text = value;
        }



    }

    public string addPoint()
    {

        return String.Format("<li><a href=" + "\" {0} \">", url) + text + "</a></li>";  
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        return String.Format("<a href=" + "\" {0} \">",url) + text + "</a>" ;   
    }



           }
       }
```

Here is my Form Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace LinkIt_
 {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HyperLink link;
            try
            {

                if (chkPoint.Checked)
                {

                    txtDisplay.Text = "";
                    link = new HyperLink(txtLink.Text, txtText.Text);
                    txtDisplay.Text = link.addPoint();


                }
                else
                {
                    txtDisplay.Text = "";
                    link = new HyperLink(txtLink.Text, txtText.Text);
                    txtDisplay.Text = link.ToString();

                }



            }


            catch (ArgumentNullException msg)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
            }





   }




    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = "";
        txtLink.Text = "";
        txtText.Text = "";
    }
}
 }
```

My Question:

1. How do I make sure that I don't create a partially initialized object?
2. If my code need correcting, Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor your code to use properties with decreased accessor visibility. 
This way the `HyperLink` objects can not be altered from outside the class (this is often a preferable attribute for data structures).

For example you could do something like this:

```
class HyperLink
{
    public String Website{get; private set;}

    public String Text {get; private set;}

    public HyperLink(string url,string text)
    {
        if(string.isNullOrEmpty(url) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
          throw new ArgumentNullException("no partially intialized object allowed");

        this.Website = url;
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public string AddPoint()
    {
        return String.Format("<li><a href=" + "\" {0} \">", url) + text + "</a></li>";  
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("<a href=" + "\" {0} \">",url) + text + "</a>" ;   
    }
}
```

---

**Update to answer question in comments**

Yes, it is perfectly reasonable to use the Getter/Setter from within the same object or class. 
However, I advise to improve your usage of `String.Format` to the following:

```
String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>",this.Link, this.Text);
```

Comment: Quick question. What if I make the setter public and have a default no argument constructor, and check to make sure that in the form the textboxes aren't empty and actually contain text, is that okay?

Comment: @SylviaRosemond That question is pretty hard to answer. It might work out for you, but it will require you to be careful while handling the objects. If you do it the way I laid out you can not get the objects into an invalid state.

Comment: @yas4891-Thanks! One more if you don't mind. In my methods, I called url/text to display the strings. However, I can't do that anymore, is it okay to call the getter/setter from my own class, for example in the toString method would now read return String.Format("<a href=" + "\" {0} \">",this.Link) + this.Text + "</a>" ;  My basic question, is it safe to call the getter in the same class?

Comment: @SylviaRosemond I incorporated the answer to you question into my original answer